# include a floating image in the title using tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

In LaTeX using tcolorbox I created this:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable,hooks}
\usepackage{minted} 
%-----------------------------
%  box example
%-----------------------------
\newtcolorbox{codigo}{drop fuzzy midday shadow,enhanced, arc=2mm, outer arc=1mm, colback=white!85!gray, colframe=black!30!blue!70,
    frame code={ \foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
    {\path [fill=gray!25!black] (interior.\n) circle (2mm); };}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{codigo}
\begin{minted}{R}
install.packages("plot3Drgl")
#install.packages("rgl")
\end{minted}
\end{codigo}
\end{document}
```

> Result:
>   [image: obtained]
>
> **What I want to get is**
>   [image: result]

Well, my goal is to create a floating "image" logo that is located either left or right, regardless of its location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overlay` for that. At the moment `pygmentize` does not seem to be friendly with your code (which is most likely my fault) so I commented out the `minted` bits, which are not central for the answer. I also replaced your image with a generic image.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable,hooks}
\usepackage{minted} 
%-----------------------------
%  box example
%-----------------------------
\newtcolorbox{codigo}{drop fuzzy midday shadow,enhanced, arc=2mm, outer arc=1mm, colback=white!85!gray, colframe=black!30!blue!70,
    frame code={ \foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
    {\path [fill=gray!25!black] (interior.\n) circle (2mm); };},
    overlay={\node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north
    east){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{codigo}
% \begin{minted}{R}
% install.packages("plot3Drgl")
% #install.packages("rgl")
% \end{minted}
Something\\
Something more
\end{codigo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to include minted?

Comment: @royer If your example works on your machine, you can just add the `overlay=...` part and it should work. I cannot get `pygmentize` run properly on my machine, so I commented that part out. The solution is independent `minted`, it works with or without as long as you have installed all the external software.

Comment: fantastic, work.